# BeautifulSoup4 find_all() behaves strange after extract() or decompose()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have observed a behavior that I found strange when using BeautifulSoup4. 
I have the following XML (filename: fake_product.xml):

```
<product acronym="ACRO1">
<formats>
    <format id="format1">
    </format>
    <format id="format2">
    </format>
    <format id="format3">
    </format>
    <format id="format4">
    </format>
    <format id="format5">
    </format>
    <format id="format6">
    </format>
</formats>
</product>
```

This `TestCase` fails:

```
import unittest
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        with open('fake_product.xml') as f:
            self.soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'xml')

    def test_product_removal(self):
        output = len(self.soup.find_all('format'))
        expected = 6
        self.assertEqual(output, expected)

        format_to_delete = self.soup.find(id='format2')
        format_to_delete.extract()
        #self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.soup.prettify(), 'xml')
        output = len(self.soup.find_all('format'))
        expected -= 1
        self.assertEqual(output, expected)
```

The reason is that the `find_all()` cannot find all the formats anymore. If I do e.g. `print self.soup.prettify()` everything looks fine to me.
If I uncomment the commented line in the TestCase and create a new BeautifulSoup object after the `extract()`, the `find_all()` seems to work fine again and the TestCase succeeds.

Can somebody explain this behavior to me?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with 4.3.2. What version of BeautifulSoup are you using?

Comment: I'm upgrading now; lets see if this is a bug introduced in the new release.

Comment: Reproduced; you go from six down to two results.

Comment: This is [already reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1483789).

Comment: Interestingly, it passes if you remove whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug introduced in 4.4.0, see the [BeautifulSoup 4 project bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1483789):

> In some situations, it seems calling `extract()` does not correctly adjust the `next_sibling` attribute of the previous element. This leaves the extracted element in the descendant generator. When later calling `find(...)` or `find_all(...)`, the search then terminates at the extracted element, causing results to be missed.

[This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1481520) is related as well and contains a potential fix:

> Lines 265, 267, 274, 277 need `!=` changing to `is not`
>
> Line 290 needs `==` changing to `is`

I can confirm that it fixes your specific test.

If you are not comfortable with editing your BeautifulSoup source code, then the work-around is to rebuild the tree as you did, or to downgrade to 4.3.2 until such time that a fix comes out.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this, i will go with rebuilding the tree